# Как position: fixed влияет на CSS свойство transform: rotateY() на устройствах iphone?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, css-animation

На сайте есть карточки с услугами (в них видео проигрывается коротенькое). Если нажать на него то карточка переворачивается и на обратной стороне текст с описанием услуги (переворот осуществляется с помощью transform: rotateY(-180deg) ).
В конце есть футер. Я хотел его сделать в паралакс эффекте (что бы он "вылазил" из под основного контента). Поэтому я задал ему position fixed и отрицательный z-index.
И в целом все работает, НО на айфон начали как то неправильно обрабатываться перевороты карточек с услугами все глючит и логает. И связано это именно с position fixed для футера, как только я его убираю все сразу нормально переворачивается. А если position fixed нет - у меня пропадает паралакс эффект на футере (что вполне логично).

Я пробовал задавать футеру position: stiky и -webkit-stiky ничего не помогает. На айфон переворот карточек начинает неправильно отрисовываться.

Вот ссылка на эту страничку с этим приколом
https://odessa.ukraine-print.com.ua/clining/index3.html